# How to implement Javascript within Salesforce Visual Force?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, salesforce, visualforce

I'm currently trying to implement javascript and html within Visual force in order to produce a graph.The below script is suppose to do this, but all I see is a blank page. The resources I'm importing include

- jquery
- D3
- Dc
- Crossfilter
- firebase
- twitter bootstrap
- dc.css
- bootstrap.css

Perhaps, it's the way I'm importing libraries through their src link, but this hasn't posed a problem before.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/master/web/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.0/dc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.0/dc.css" media="screen" /> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" /> 


</head>

<body>
<div class='pie-graph span6' id='dc-magnitude-chart'></div>
<script type = "text/javascript">


new Firebase('https://MYFIREBASE.firebaseIO.com/BetaActivities').on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var lst = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {lst.push(childSnapshot.val());});
    ndx = new crossfilter(lst);

    var XDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.Owner;});
    var YDimension = XDimension.group().reduceCount(function(d) {return d.Owner;});
    dc.barChart("#dc-magnitude-chart")
        .width(480).height(150)
        .dimension(XDimension)                                
        .group(YDimension)
        .centerBar(true)
        .gap(56)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(XDimension))
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .xAxisLabel("Market Developer")
        .yAxisLabel("Unique Counts")
        .elasticY(true)
        .xAxis().tickFormat(function(v) {return v;}); 
    dc.renderAll();

    });

</script>


</body>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using your code to help another user and ended up solving your code:

Reason why you are seeing blanks:

Look at the answer by Keith C

source : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45455/using-dc-js-d3-js-and-crossfilter-in-visualforce/45461?noredirect=1#comment59006_45461

> When running JavaScript you should always have your browser's
>   developer tools displayed, particularly the JavaScript console. If you
>   do (at least in Chrome and probably other browsers too), you will find
>   that all the http:// requests are blocked:
>
> [blocked] The page at '...' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure
>   content from '...': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
>   which will cause your page to fail.
>
> Change to https:// locations as the original page is loaded via
>   https://

```
<apex:page showheader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.d3js)}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://rawgithub.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/master/web/js/crossfilter.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.1/dc.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.1/dc.css"/> 
<apex:stylesheet value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
<body>
<div class='pie-graph span6' id='dc-magnitude-chart'></div>
<script type = "text/javascript">


new Firebase('https://shippy.firebaseIO.com/BetaActivities').on('value', function (snapshot) {
    var lst = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {lst.push(childSnapshot.val());});
    ndx = new crossfilter(lst);

    var XDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.Owner;});
    var YDimension = XDimension.group().reduceCount(function(d) {return d.Owner;});
    dc.barChart("#dc-magnitude-chart")
        .width(480).height(150)
        .dimension(XDimension)                                
        .group(YDimension)
        .centerBar(true)
        .gap(56)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(XDimension))
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .xAxisLabel("Market Developer")
        .yAxisLabel("Unique Counts")
        .elasticY(true)
        .xAxis().tickFormat(function(v) {return v;}); 
    dc.renderAll();

    });

</script>


</body>
</apex:page>
```

[image]